# CSS :not() with [attribute*=value] selector not works properly

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-selectors

I'm using `[class*="menu-class-"]:not(.menu-class-2)` for my `<li>` elements, it works properly. The problem is when I want to point to the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>`, `[class*="menu-class-"]:not(.menu-class-2) a`. For some reason it doesn't work.

CSS:

```
.nav-menu .menu-class > .sub-menu li[class*="menu-class-"]:not(.menu-class-2) {
    display: table-cell;
}

.nav-menu .menu-class > .sub-menu li[class*="menu-class-"]:not(.menu-class-2) a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
    <li class="menu-class">
        <a href="#12">Nav 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-class-3">
                <a href="#12">Nav 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-class-2"><a href="#2">Anchor, it should be lowercase</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is the `<a>` inside the `<li class="menu-class-2">` is uppercase, but it should be lowercase, because I didn't add any property for this element. The container of the `<a>` (`<li class="menu-class-2">`), didn't get the `display:table-cell` property, so it works properly.

The JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/qnzos5t4/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you **do have** a li that is not `.menu-class-2`:

```
<ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
    <li class="menu-class">
        <a href="#12">Nav 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-class-3">  <!-- THIS ONE HERE -->
                <a href="#12">Nav 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-class-2"><a href="#2">Anchor, it should be lowercase</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since your css rule is using a whitespace to select the anchor after the li, every `<a>` descendant of it, will be uppercase. You need to use a child selector:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnzos5t4/4/)

```
.nav-menu .menu-class > .sub-menu li[class*="menu-class-"]:not(.menu-class-2) > a {
```